# Teradata to mysql conversion - qualify and rank

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I have a teradata code which as shown below:

```
select *
from date_dim a
left join 
(select incident_number,incident_type,submit_date from itamr qualify RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY incident_number ORDER BY last_modified_date DESC) = 1)b
on a.Clndr_Dt = b.submit_date
and b.incident_type = 'Request';
```

I need to convert the qualify rank and partition to mysql.
I tried grouping instead of partition.
Could someone help me out on how to convert qualify and rank in mysql?

Comment: Qualify is strictly a Teradata thing.  Rank() should work fine in Mysql, at least on modern versions. Show us your current MySql query and let's see what's going with it.

Answer (score 1):

QUALIFY is a teradata propriety keyword. Howover RANK function will work with any Relational DB. You can replace QUALIFY statement with a subquery as below:

```
 select *
from date_dim a
left join 
(
select * from 
(select incident_number,incident_type,submit_date ,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY incident_number ORDER BY last_modified_date DESC) rn
from itamr ) sub where rn = 1 ) b
on a.Clndr_Dt = b.submit_date
and b.incident_type = 'Request';
```